# Name of a certain math font

Tags: fonts, math-mode

I want to reproduce the "x" as in the picture below

[image: font to reproduce]

The closest I can get is `\bm{\mathsf{x}}`, but it's not the same.

EDIT: one more example:

[image: font to reproduce]

"x" and "t" are the only characters I have for this font.

Comment: that's a very heavy x, looks almost like a display font. where did the image come from? If you have it in pdf or some other amenable format you can discover the font rather than just trying to recognise it in an image.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks, but I'm not able to share the original pdf publicly. What tools can be used to discover the font? Thanks.

Comment: well simplest thing is to just use acrobat reader and then look at the document properties  Fonts tab, that lists all the fonts in the document, which is a shorter list than all the fonts in the world as candidates for which one has the X. Of course even better than pdf is if you have the tex or word or whatever sources and can see the commands that made the x

Comment: Why do you want this specific font? It's not really special and isn't even used correctly (the x-height is different). If you just need a heavy sans serif font, look at [URW Grotesq](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/grotesk/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it is from Chris Bishops Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning. He uses Helvetica Bold for this "t" and "x".

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{helvet}
\begin{document}

\[p(\text{\textbf{\textsf{t}}}|\text{\textbf{\textsf{x}}},\mathbf{w},\beta)\]

\end{document}
```

I think `\text{\textbf{\textsf{t}}}` is not very nice, but it works.

Comment: `\textbf` already enters text mode, so there's no need for the `\text`. And one should consider using `\usepackage[scaled=0.82]{helvet}` to at least match the x-height of the fonts.